# How to handle errors/exceptions in swift

Tags: swift, error-handling, nsdate

That title sounds pretty general although its a specific problem. I just didn't know how to describe it in a better way...
I've read quite a lot about error handling in swift. But I still cant figure out how to solve this simple (at least in objective-C) task.
I have a textfield and want to read out the string-value...than format it in an `Date` value. No problem so far. But if you type in a value that does not match the specified date format I get an error back (which is ok...its not the right format). In this case I just want a standard value to be saved. In Objective-C I would have done this with a `@try`-`@catch` loop. That kind of exception handling does not exist in swift anymore does it?
Here is my (Swift 2) code. Hope somebody has an answer.

```
func getDateFromTextfield() throws -> NSDate
{
    let formatter:NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"
    formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")

// Here should be a "throw expression" but I dont know how to set it. 

    let date = formatter.dateFromString(dictOfLabelsAndText["Birthdate"] as! String)!

    return date
}

do
{
    child.birthdateAT = try self.getDateFromTextfield()
}
catch {
    child.birthdateAT = formatter.dateFromString("01.01.2000")
    print("wrong date") //Or whatever error
}
```

Comment: Also, if you might not have a valid birthdate, rather than storing 1/1/2000, I might suggest defining `birthdateAT` such that it is optional. It's much better to represent an unknown birthdate as `nil` than `1/1/2000`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Swift `do`-`try`-`catch` syntax is designed to handle the errors analogous to the `NSError` patterns in Objective-C, not for handling fatal errors/exceptions. Do not be confused by the similarity of Swift's error handling `do`-`try`-`catch` with the completely different Objective-C exception handling pattern of `@try`-`@catch`.

One should only use forced unwrapping (`!`) and forced type casting (`as!`) when one knows with certainty that they cannot possibly fail. If they could fail (as in this case), you should gracefully detect this scenario and handle it accordingly.

You could, for example, use Swift error handling to communicate a failure converting a string to a date (and then use `do`-`try`-`catch` pattern when you call it in order to detect and handle that error):

```swift
enum DateError: Error {
    case badDate
    case dateNotFound
}

func getDateFromTextfield() throws -> Date {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
    
    guard let dateString = dictOfLabelsAndText["Birthdate"] as? String else {
        throw DateError.dateNotFound
    }
    
    guard let date = formatter.date(from: dateString) else {
        throw DateError.badDate
    }
    
    return date
}
```

Then you could do:

```swift
do {
    child.birthdateAT = try getDateFromTextfield()
} catch {
    child.birthdateAT = formatter.date(from: "01.01.2000")
}
```

Or, more concisely, use `try?` and `nil` coalescing operator:

```swift
child.birthdateAT = try? getDateFromTextfield() ?? formatter.date(from: "01.01.2000")
```

Alternatively, you might just change the method to return an optional and use `nil` as a way of detecting a failure:

```swift
func getDateFromTextfield() -> Date? {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
    
    guard let dateString = dictOfLabelsAndText["Birthdate"] as? String else {
        return nil
    }
    
    return formatter.date(from: dateString)
}
```

And then do:

```swift
if let birthDate = getDateFromTextfield() {
    child.birthdateAT = birthDate
} else {
    child.birthdateAT = formatter.date(from: "01.01.2000")
}
```

Or, again, use the `nil` coalescing operator:

```swift
child.birthdateAT = getDateFromTextfield() ?? formatter.date(from: "01.01.2000")
```

But, bottom line, do not use `!` to unwrap an optional unless you know it can never be `nil`. Otherwise, use optional binding and/or `guard` statements to gracefully detect and report the failure.

---

This has been updated for contemporary versions of Swift. For original Swift 2 answer, see [previous revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/35655930/6) of this answer.

Comment: forced unwrapping (!) and forced casting (as!) raise a runtime error, not an exception, not what can be "thrown"

Comment: My point is merely that the OP was conflating the Objective-C "exception handling" and the Swift error handling and that one cannot use `catch` to handle failures arising from forced unwrapping or forced type casting. I've tried to simplify the answer accordingly.

Comment: Great answer. I used the 2nd possibility to solve the problem. Nevertheless that "guard" statement solution is really helpful understanding error handling in swift (although it is much more complicated than it used to be...:) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Choose your errors - something like

```
enum DateError: ErrorType {
    case BadDate
    case Whatever
}
```

And throw it where your comment is

```
throw DateError.BadDate
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3**
**I tried this. It works but not sure if it is the right method**

```
 enum DateError: Error, CustomStringConvertible {

    case badDate

    var description: String {
        switch self {

        case .badDate:
            return "Error: Invalid date detected."
        }
    }


}


func convertAMtoDateTime(amTime: String) throws -> String{


    let fromFormat: String = "hh:mm a"

    let toFormat: String = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"

    let formatter = DateFormatter()

    formatter.dateFormat = fromFormat

    let amDate = formatter.date(from: amTime)

    let dateTimeFormatter    = DateFormatter()

    dateTimeFormatter.dateFormat = toFormat

    var dateTime: String = ""

    if(amDate != nil){

         dateTime = dateTimeFormatter.string(from: amDate!)

    }
    else{

        throw DateError.badDate

    }

    return dateTime


}
```